# What command is need to set the time on a Windows server when it boots?

Tags: windows, boot, ntp

I am running a Windows server on a VM and the time isn't accurate after it reboots.

Is there a command  to set the time on a Windows 2008 via NTP when it boots?

It needs to run at boot time not at logon time.

Comment: why the votes to close it?

Answer (score 0):

`w32tm /resync`

This requires that you have a valid time provider configured. If this computer is joined to a domain it will sync the time with one of your domain controllers.

Comment: where are the providers configured? the server is a standalone server, not part of a domain. Can the command work with the ntp servers configured in the Time and Date applet

Comment: I am not entirely sure if it can pull the data out of this configuration, you'd better configure the external ntp servers directly in the registry. Have a Look at [KB816042](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042/en-us) starting from this section: **Configuring the Windows Time service to use an external time source**